# What is the best way of displaying a long title in a text editor?

Tags: text-editor

I was wondering what is the alternative way to show a big title without it having show it into a next line. For example please see the attached picture.[image]

Comment: Why dont you want it to go to another line?

Comment: scrolling marquees everywhere!

Answer (score 3):

You can have an ellipsis (ie, three consecutive periods) enclosed in square brackets like so.

***Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [...]***

This practice used to be the MLA standard for omitting text from a direct quote around a decade ago. I've just learned the current standard is to have three periods with spaces in between and no brackets. However, the new standard isn't as obvious to me; brackets quickly let the reader know the ellipses isn't part of the original title.

Comment: Also, use the title attribute to show the entire text. In hml5, you can use the title attribute in every element so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as screen real estate for one you are giving up too much with that font size and bold.
It only need to be enough bigger than the description for them to see the difference.

Clearly the full title is of value.
A few options

- mouse over display it in a tooltip
- have an expander option that it drops down to multi line
  the click the expandar again to collapse
  if they need the option to edit the title then this is best
- let them scroll horizontally in the title
  this is how the url behaves in most browsers